# Картинка в HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, html5, flask

пишу свой сайт на flask с помощью питона 3.6, для подключения ИИ (imageai). Хочу кидать картинку, flask её скачает, потом ИИ будет думать что на картинке и в конце мне должно выводить картинку которую проверил ИИ. index.html находится в папке `templates`, а картинка в папке `uploads`. Код -

```
@app.route('/ai/<filename>')`

def ai(filename):

    return '<img src="./uploads/'+filename+'">'
```

А вывод - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А я хочу чтобы выводило - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, если я вставляю вместо `return '<img src="./uploads/'+filename+'">'` - `return '<img href="https:/ssilochka-na.kartinky/img.png">'` всё работает. Я не понимаю как мне указать именно файл на моём компе. Помогите люди добрые)

Comment: посмотрите на функцию `url_for` - она как раз нужна для генерации корректного url-адреса

Comment: Подробнее можно?

Comment: Вот ссылка на документацию https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=url_for#flask.url_for , а вот здесь есть пример реализации https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#url-building

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю

Comment: @cauf, не помогло:(
Всё равно не смог сделать, ссылка получилась но она относится только к файлу ai.html в папке templates. Што мне делать? Я не знаю как мне создать ссылку к файлу png в папке upload (папка upload находится в папке templates)

Comment: http://letmegooglethat.com/?q=flask+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B

Comment: @alex но это не статика. Это медиа. Немного по-другому обрабатываются. Во всяком случае в джанге.

Comment: @YDCdeveloper кмк, нужно вытащить папку `uploads` из `templates`. У тебя это будет не статичные файлы, которые складываются отдельно и всегда остаются одними и теми же между запросами к сайту, а медиа - контент. получаемый от пользователя и/или генирируемый в следствии взаимодействия с сайтом. [Вот эту ветку](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/) документации читал? Все сделал? Что получилось? Можешь еще посмотреть [вот этот пакет](https://pythonhosted.org/flask-media/) для работы с медиа. Он как раз возвращает урлы для файлов